# Returning count for an odata query

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

If I have a query such as:

```
http://myCRMOrg/api/data/v8.1/accounts?$filter=_chr_accountstatusid_value%20eq%2079A024B5-3D7C-E211-8B29-00155DC86B6F%20and%20accountid%20eq%20e929baaf-483b-e711-9425-00155dc0d345&$count=true
```

Please notice that I am specifying `$count=true`

It will return:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://myCRMORG/api/data/v8.1/$metadata#accounts","@odata.count":1,"value":[
    {
      "@odata.etag":"W/\"1812635\"","
      //100 fields and lots of data
    }
  ]
}
```

How can we reconstruct this query to simply return **1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue. What I did is I added count before filter and it worked. Example:

```
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/accounts/$count/?$select=accountid&$filter=accountid%20eq%20D1C4CD52-1E51-E711-8122-6C3BE5B3B698&", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question properly because if you filter Accounts by AccountId, you'll only ever get 0 or 1 results. So, if you get a result, you know the count is 1.

Anyway, to get a count, you can use a proper FetchXml aggregate like so:

```
https://xedev29.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts?fetchXml=
<fetch aggregate='true'>
    <entity name='account'>
        <attribute name='accountid' aggregate='count' alias='Count' />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://xedev29.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#accounts","value":[
    {
      "Count":337
    }
  ]
}
```

And feel free to add your filters to the FetchXml:

```
https://xedev29.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts?fetchXml=
<fetch aggregate='true'>
    <entity name='account'>
    <attribute name='accountid' aggregate='count' alias='Count' />
        <filter type='and' >
            <condition attribute='chr_accountstatusid' operator='eq' value='D1C4CD52-1E51-E711-8122-6C3BE5B3B698'/>
            <condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Of course you are subject to the usual FetchXml aggregate limitations (i.e. count tops out at 50K rows). Though I have discovered ways around this if you need it.

I also should have mentioned that there's no need to return all the fields, so we can use &$select=accountid.

You can get the @odata.count with an associative reference: `result["@odata.count"]`

Here's a full example:

```
function count(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=accountid&$filter=accountid%20eq%20D1C4CD52-1E51-E711-8122-6C3BE5B3B698&$count=true", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
                console.log(result["@odata.count"]);
            } else {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Furthermore, I should mention that if you're doing significant work with the WebAPI, [Jason Lattimer's CRMRESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) is very handy.

And you might also want to check out [David Yack's WebAPI helper](https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI).

Comment: well i'm just trying to determine the fastest way to know whether the result set is empty

Comment: OK, then it might help to post your onSuccess callback code... In there I imagine you'll want to check if results == null or results[0] == null.